# Golang HTTP XML Parsing issue

Tags: xml, http, parsing, go

I'm trying to access an XML file available online, but after the GET the XML format disappears.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you so much!

```
func getHttp(address string) string{
    resp, err := http.Get(address)
    resp.Header.Add("Content-Type","application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return (string(data))
}
```

The new format looks like this:

```
{"SessionKey":"229eaeaa9fb14a0d85ff38ae4e0c7870_ecilpojl_018FC93424D13ECC0908CE5BC5E3F86B","Query":{"Country":"GB","Currency":"GBP","Locale":"en-gb","Adults":1,"Children":0,"Infants":0,"OutboundDate":"2016-10-08","LocationSchema":"Default","CabinClass":"Economy","GroupPricing":false},
```

instead of

```
<SessionKey>229eaeaa9fb14a0d85ff38ae4e0c7870_ecilpojl_018FC93424D13ECC0908CE5BC5E3F86B</SessionKey>
  <Query>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <Locale>en-gb</Locale>
    <Adults>1</Adults>
    <Children>0</Children>
    <Infants>0</Infants>
    <OutboundDate>2016-10-08</OutboundDate>
    <LocationSchema>Default</LocationSchema>
    <CabinClass>Economy</CabinClass>
    <GroupPricing>false</GroupPricing>
  </Query>
```

Comment: The problem is in your main. Show your main function: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   and you don't need: `resp.Header.Add("Content-Type","application/xml; charset=utf-8")`

Comment: In my main i just call this function with the web address

Comment: So it is JSON not XML

Comment: If I click on the link the browser generates an xml file, but after the GET it changes

Comment: The server is sending json based on the request, maybe the user agent in this case. Why not use the json? It will be easier to unmarshal and contain the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending

Try this (and replace the web address with yours):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getHttp(`http://stackoverflow.com/`))
}
func getHttp(url string) string {    
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("ACCEPT", "application/xhtml+xml,application/xml")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(data)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Content-Type is for the data in the request but you're not sending any. The Accept header is the standard way to request a data type.

Comment: You don't specify the encoding. Just `("Accept", "application/xml")`